# In some cases will not Shutdown (in Net framework 4.5 good work but Net framework 3.0 an error)

Tags: c++, shutdown

I'm using the code below for Shutdown

```
        bool ShutdownWin(int Action){
        HANDLE hToken;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

        if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
            TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)){
            //Not successful

        }
        else{
            LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME,
                &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

            tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;   
            tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0,
                (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS){
                //Not successful
                return false;
            }
            else{

                if (!ExitWindowsEx(Action | EWX_FORCEIFHUNG,
                    SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OPERATINGSYSTEM |
                    SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_UPGRADE |
                    SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED)){
                    //Not successful
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    //successful
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And I'm calling it the following code:

```
        if (ShutdownWin(EWX_SHUTDOWN)==false){
        if ((MessageBox::Show("Shutdown", "Try again for shutdown", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo) == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes))
        {
            ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"shutdown",
                L"/s /t 0",
                NULL, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
        }
    }
```

According to the said agreement

In some cases (in Windows 8.1), show the stage shutdown, but not shutdown

in Net framework 4.5 good work
but Net framework 3.0 an error
please help me

Comment: It's unclear to me from your description: do all the API functions you call succeed and yet Windows 8.1 still does not shut down?

Comment: API is Ok But In some cases not shutdown. Only in the version that worked with Net framework 4.5, but now I use the Net framework 3.0 is corrupted